# Keep people from opening pdf directly on my webiste

Tags: .htaccess, pdf, redirect

I am not sure if this is possible, but I figure I would ask.

I have hundred of PDF's stored on my website, and they are all getting indexed directly by Google, so people are doing a search and the engine is taking them directly to the PDF.  The issue here is that the PDF's are related to language learning and have audios that go with them.  If a visitor goes directly to the PDF, then they never see the audios.

I have another page I have designed which opens up the PDF in an Iframe, and shows the audios right next to them so the users can use it.

So my question is, is it possible to redirect a user who opens:

www.mywebsite.com/something.pdf

And have it redirect them to:

www.mywebsite.com/page-with-audios/

The key here is that the pdf should still open in the IFrame on my domain.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use routing, you could make a route which has the PDF name as parameter. The route could look something like this:

`/{PDF_NAME}.pdf`

This could be used to match all PDF's, like `example.com/foo.pdf`, `example.com/bar-baz.pdf`. Since you then have the name of the PDF they would like to view, you can redirect them to the `/page-with-audio-files` with some extra data like the name of the PDF. Then you can handle opening the iFrame.

### EDIT

since I now see your question was directed at `.htaccess`, I think the following might work too.

add this rewrite to your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\-]+.pdf)$ /page-with-audio/$1 [L, R=301]
```

This will make the `$1` variable `somepdf.pdf` if your request url is `http://example.com/somepdf.pdf`.

Then it redirects the user to `http://example.com/page-with-audio/somepdf.pdf` so you know which pdf was requested.